# Double free when using lambda to function pointer cast

Tags: c++, function, gcc, lambda

After spending many days debugging a very obscure error in a complicated program, I finally reduced the problem to a very simple, reproducible scenario.

Basically, it appears that if I have a simple non-capturing lambda with a signature that takes a single argument by value (and returns an object by value), and I convert that lambda to an equivalent function pointer type and then invoke the function pointer, the destructor of the object passed as an argument is incorrectly invoked.

Here's a simple reproducible case that shows the problem, and causes a double-free using GCC 4.9.2:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <utility>
#include <cassert>

struct Foo
{
    Foo() = default;
    Foo(const Foo&) = delete;
    Foo& operator = (const Foo&) = delete;

    ~Foo()
    {
        std::cout << "Destroying object " << this << std::endl;
    }
};

auto callback = [](std::unique_ptr<Foo> p)
{
    assert(p);
    return p;
};

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<Foo> ptr(new Foo());
    auto fptr = static_cast<std::unique_ptr<Foo>(*)(std::unique_ptr<Foo>)>(callback);
    auto result = fptr(std::move(ptr));
}
```

The intended behavior of this program is to allocate a unique instance of `Foo` managed by a `unique_ptr`.  Then move that instance once by passing it as an argument to `callback`, then move the instance again when `callback` returns it by value, and finally destruct the instance.  (Granted the compiler may also remove at least one of the move constructor calls using copy-elision, but that's not important here.)

So therefore I should really only see `Foo`'s destructor called once.

Instead I see this when I run this program:

```
Destroying object 0xdf4410
Destroying object 0xdf4410
*** Error in `./test9': double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x0000000000df4410 ***
```

Somehow, the compiler is generating code that incorrectly invokes the `unique_ptr` destructor when it is passed to `callback`.

Note that this *only* happens if I convert the non-capturing lambda to an equivalent function pointer.  If I invoke `callback` directly, there is no problem.

So I can't see why this would happen, and therefore I am asking if this is likely a compiler bug with lambda to function pointer conversion, or if I am just doing something wrong here.

Comment: Can't reproduce.

Comment: I'm using GCC 4.9.2 on Linux and compiling with `-std=c++14`

Comment: can't reproduce with g++ 8.3.0 and clang++ 7.0.1; I suspect a bug in g++ 4.9.2

Comment: Also reproduced it with G++ 5.3.1

Comment: Could not reproduce the error, but did reproduce the two dtor calls which just should not happen for memory managed by a `std::unique_ptr`. It is most likely a bug.

Answer (score 0):

It wasn't fixed until gcc6.1 according to godbolt's test.
There is an obvious difference between 2 different version's compilers for the function lambda::_FUN that is generated by compiler automatically. The function is used to call lambda::operator().

```
for gcc4.9
lambda::_FUN(unique_ptr<Foo> ptr)
    tmp = ptr //copy constructor is called by compiler, although it's already declared as "delete". it means there are 2 owners for same Foo object.
    lambda::operator(tmp)

for gcc 6.1 or higher
lambda::_FUN(unique_ptr<Foo> ptr)
    lambda::operator(ptr)
```